# Scanner with excellent Linux support and ADF (up to 1000 EUR)

Tags: linux, scanner

Need a scanner, price up to **1000 EUR**.

Absolute requirements:

- Excellent Linux support under Debian
- Automatic Document Feeder (ADF) for at least 20 pages in A4 format
- Duplex
- At least 300 DPI
- USB connection to computer

Nice to have:

- Only packages from Debian repositories required
- Fast operation (we have loads of pages to scan)
- 600 DPI or higher
- Optional scanning to USB stick without any computer

"Excellent Linux support" in particular means that we can easily start a scan from a tool like gscan2pdf, and it will scan all the pages in the ADF into a single PDF file. It should also be possible to scan some more pages after this and have them added to the same PDF file.

**Conclusion:** We bought the *Brother ADS-3600W*. It did not work out-of-the-box under Debian/buster, but we had to download a DEB file from Brother's homepage, which currently is`brscan5-1.2.2-0.amd64.deb`. Installing this DEB and rebooting made all scan programs recognize the device. Of course, it would be much, much nicer if Brother offered a *repository* instead, so that updates would come via `apt`.

We mostly use `gscan2pdf`. It works fine in the range up to documents about 70 pages (scanning up to 50 pages at a time, since the scanner has a 50 page feeder). After this, it becomes very slow, almost unusable. We suspect this is a problem with program `gscan2pdf` and not with the scanner or its driver. Waiting and hoping for a new version of the program.

We also received verbal confirmation from Epson that the *Workforce DS-870* does work with SANE under Linux. This scanner has a 100 page feeder and would thus have been better. However, since Epson insisted on prehistoric communication (that is, via phone and not e-mail), this message arrived too late, after we already ordered the Brother. Maybe next time.

Comment: Recently scanner/printer producers started to standardize. I bought an ancient scanner and use it through a windows vm, but... well...

Comment: We are considering the Epson WorkForce DS-870 now. It is _not_ listed on the SANE website (http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html) as a supported device. But on the vendor homepage it says that "SANE (Linux)" is supported. Anyone has experience with this model?